# User Profile Property locked down and un-editable

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service

Brand new SharePoint 2013 on premise, sync with AD successful however the field Office Location (SPS-Location) is set as "Configure a Term Set to be used for this property" but I cannot select the term set, even the check box of the above control is grayed out (cannot remove it, cannot select term set).

How to get out of this without deleting the property and re-creating it again?

Comment: Is your term store up and running. Do you have rights to edit it? Mare sure the Managed Metadata Service is running.

Comment: yes, it is up and running. I would also consider NOT using metadata and leave the field as free text but unfortunately I cannot uncheck the box

Comment: Can you create a custom location field and link that one to mmd? Maybe you can not modifiy the build-in SharePoint fields.

Comment: Yes, I have tried and I am not able to link it to mmd, which is not priority n.1 for me. So you are saying that there is no way to fix it. In every other place where I have seen this property it was always editable by the user with free text since it is not mapped.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Edit the Office Location Profile property and turn it into a free text instead of using a term set (that I cannot even select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution myself. Still not able to unchecked that check-box, however by changing a setting in central admin.

In the Managed metadata service (the proxy one, not the actual one) I checked the box called `This service application is the default storage location for column specific term sets.`

It then allowed me to select a term set. Problem solved mostly.